# Hi guys I'm new to programming languages and trying to make a discord bot

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

so I was following tutorial provided on youtube to make a discord bot
but in the mid of tutorial I got errors which is not mentioned in the tutorial and now I'm stuck
I'm attempting to make discord autorole bot
my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const Blue = '721179394260860990';
const Red = '721179217718673419';
const Yellow = '721179456701595719';

const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {

    if (message.content == 'Blue') {
        message.member.addRole(Blue);
    }
    else if (message.content == 'Red') {
        message.member.addRole(Red);
    }
    else if (message.content == 'Yellow') {
        message.member.addRole(Yellow);
    }

});
```

when I run the code it says 
>

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:12
        message.member.addRole(Blue);
                       ^

TypeError: message.member.addRole is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:12:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
```

I'm pretty sure I followed the tutorials correctly but still I got this error
pls help me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that discord **changed** the function, so now there is **not** an .addRole function for users.
For the users you now have to do:

```
message.member.roles.add(Blue);
```